# Producer-consumer queue with the ability to move items to the front

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I implemented a producer-consumer pattern with Java's LinkedBlockingDeque, but I have hit a problem, that I sometimes want to move an item (which is alread somewhere in the queue) to the front of the queue, so it is processed sooner. I never know which of the already enqueued items would be good to move to the front. So I would like the LinkedBlockingDeque to be replaced by something, where I can reorder items. I have one producer and 2-4 consumers (custom Thread implementation) and I am on Android platform. How can I do this? Some blocking double connected linked list?

Comment: Can you not just do remove(Object o), retrieve the object after removal and then addFirst(Object o). You use the iterator to check what object are inside the Deque.

Comment: I did it this way and it works good. I would like to have a feature not to move the item to from if it is close enough to the front, so I do not get unnecessary removes. Is there a fast way (with LinkedBlockingDeque) to check how far is an item in the queue? By fast I mean O(1), max O(log N) and without copying the whole queue.

Comment: @Tom Cammann If you post that comment as an answer I will accpet it as it is the best advice I have received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

You could use `remove(Object o)` to retrieve the object and remove it from the queue, then use `addFirst(Object o)` to add it to the front of the queue. This will have the effect of prioritising this object.

You use the iterator to check what object are inside the Deque. However be very careful of `ConcurrentModificationException` as they could be raised if you are accessing the Collection in one thread and modifying it in another, however if you are using a blockingQueue this shouldn't be an issue.

From [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) Javadoc:

> BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods
>   achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms
>   of concurrency control. However, the bulk Collection operations
>   addAll, containsAll, retainAll and removeAll are not necessarily
>   performed atomically unless specified otherwise in an implementation.
>   So it is possible, for example, for addAll(c) to fail (throwing an
>   exception) after adding only some of the elements in c.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html).  It will probably suit your needs.  You can insert items with a nominal priority, and then when you want to adjust some of the element's priorities, you remove it from the queue and re-add it with the new priority.

Comment: that has a problem, that I have to remember the biggest priority, which will always increase. hmm, but that should not be a big problem, as I should never produce more than million items per app start. I wll try, thanks.

Comment: Note it uses lower priorities for the head of the queue.  I was thinking you could add all items with 100 priority (at which point they are ordered by order of entry), and only adjust when needed.  You can always get the priority of the front of the queue by doing a `peek`.

Comment: that is a problem, I can have up to ~400 items in the queue

Comment: If you use `ints` as your priority, you are allowed to have negative priorities (which would be closer to the front of the queue).  So, you can go to -2^31, or roughly -2 billion.  In addition, the queue lets you define the priority with a `Comparator`, so you can use whatever you want in reality. If you like higher numbers for priorities, define you` Comparator` to do that.

Comment: I realised that when I must remove the object, change priority and then put it back, I can do what Tom Cammann sayed in his comment. I already implemented it that way and it gives me a bit better results than my previous implementation.